# Refreshing Live Chart on button click event

Tags: wpf, data-binding, livecharts

I have Live Chart that I am trying to perform a fresh of the values on `Button_Click` event but the Chart is not refreshing.

I have two `TextBoxes` where the user can select the start and end date they would like to review and use the `butn_ExecuteQuery_Click` to display the data.

```
    public HBDBreakdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChartValues();
    }

    private void ChartValues()
    {
        try
        {
            // Defines the variable for differnt lines.
            List<double> SmallCommercialIndustValues = new List<double>();
            List<double> ResidentialValues = new List<double>();
            List<string> AnalystName = new List<string>();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\MSSQLSERVER2;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;user id=sa; password=Westside2$; Integrated Security=False;");

            string selectQuery = ("SELECT Users.TX_EMPLOYEE, SUM(CASE WHEN d .REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Residential, SUM(CASE WHEN d .REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SmallCommercialIndust FROM hb_Disputes AS d INNER JOIN Users ON d.ASSGNTO = Users.KY_USER_ID WHERE(d.OPENED >=@OPENED) AND(d.OPENED < @CLOSED) GROUP BY Users.TX_EMPLOYEE; ");
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

            command.Parameters.Add("@OPENED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtepicker_Open.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@CLOSED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtepicker_DateResolved.Text;

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                // Check for DBNull and then assign the variable
                if (sqlReader["SmallCommercialIndust"] != DBNull.Value)
                    SmallCommercialIndustValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["SmallCommercialIndust"]));

                // Check for DBNull and then assign the variable
                if (sqlReader["Residential"] != DBNull.Value)
                    ResidentialValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Residential"]));

                // Check for DBNull and then assign the variable
                AnalystName.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["TX_EMPLOYEE"]));
            }


            SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
           {
            new StackedColumnSeries
            {
                Title = "Residential",
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(ResidentialValues),
                StackMode = StackMode.Values, // this is not necessary, values is the default stack mode
                DataLabels = true
            },
            new StackedColumnSeries
            {
                Title = "Small Commercial Indust",
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(SmallCommercialIndustValues),
                StackMode = StackMode.Values,
                DataLabels = true
            }
            };

            Labels = AnalystName.ToArray();
            //Formatter = value => value + " Disputes";

           DataContext = this;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
    public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }

    private void butn_ExecuteQuery_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Refresh Chart
        ChartValues();
    }
```

Comment: What if you set `DataContext = null;` before calling `ChartValues`? Or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the setters of the source properties like `SeriesCollection`.

Comment: @mm8 Setting ``DataContext = null;`` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `DataContext = null;` before you call `ChartValues()` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the setters of the source properties.

Answer (score 0):

Better never reset the `DataContext` only to update the data binding of certain properties. This results in very bad performance as the complete view will be forced to render again. The `DataContext` is also inherited down the element tree.
Better write cleaner code and handle dynamic data more gracefully and as intended by the framework (see [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)).

Inside a control (or on a `DependencyObject` in general) you should always implement all properties that are involved in data binding as `DependencyProperty`.
They will automatically refresh the target and depending on the `Binding.Mode` also the source of the specific `Binding`.
Since you are *reassigning* `SeriesCollection` and `Labels`, both properties should be a `DependencyProperty`.

In your case, you can go without implementing dependency properties, because you are only updating collections. So simply avoid reassigning a new collection on each refresh and instead use `IList.Clear` and `IList.Add` on collections that implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://%C2%B4https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

`SeriesCollection` already implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so you only need to change the type of the `Labels` property from `string[]` to `ObservableCollection<string>`. This way `IList.Clear` and `IList.Add` operations will be automatically reflected by the binding target (the chart control):

```
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> Labels { get; set; }

public HBDBreakdown()
{
    InitializeComponent();
   
    // Set the `DataContext` once in the constructor
    this.DataContext = this;

    // Initialize the collection to prepare them for dynamic clear/add
    this.SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();
    this.Labels = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}

private void ChartValues()
{
    try
    {
        ...

        this.SeriesCollection.Clear();
        this.SeriesCollection.Add(
          new StackedColumnSeries
          {
            Title = "Residential",
            Values = new ChartValues<double>(ResidentialValues),
            StackMode = StackMode.Values, // this is not necessary, values is the default stack mode
            DataLabels = true
          });

        this.SeriesCollection.Add(
          new StackedColumnSeries
          {
            Title = "Small Commercial Indust",
            Values = new ChartValues<double>(SmallCommercialIndustValues),
            StackMode = StackMode.Values,
            DataLabels = true
          });

        this.Labels.Clear();
        AnalystName.ForEach(this.Labels.Add);
    }
    // Code smell: never catch 'Exception'. 
    // Only catch explicitly those exception you can handle.
    // A user can't handle exceptions, so in a real business application you wouldn't show the exception message to the user.
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Bad practice
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Please also read: Exceptions and Exception Handling, especially [Exceptions Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/#exceptions-overview) and [Design Guidelines for Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/using-standard-exception-types).